# How to read a file from Amazon S3 Using Apache Spark without writing it in local file?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I have files stored in Amazon S3 cloud. I want to parse file partially. I try this method to read file. But it's taking too much time. because first it's writing this file into local file. Spark is parsing it with local saved file.
Is there any way to read file from AmazonS3 directly using spark.

I have tried this way;

```
package com.elegant.amazon;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3Object;

public class AmazonS3Spark {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int numOfLinesRead = 0;
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("SparkCassandraApp")
                .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost")
                .config("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042").master("local[*]").getOrCreate();
        String outPutFile = "/home/vipin/mylocalfile.csv";
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(outPutFile);
        S3Object s3object = AmazonS3Util.s3Client
                .getObject(new GetObjectRequest("flightdata-em", "2015/On_Time_On_Time_Performance_2015_1.csv"));

        InputStreamReader decoder = new InputStreamReader(s3object.getObjectContent());
        BufferedReader buffered = new BufferedReader(decoder);
        buffered.mark(numOfLinesRead);
        int numOfLinesToRead = 1000;
        String thisLine = null;
        Long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while ((thisLine = buffered.readLine()) != null && numOfLinesRead < numOfLinesToRead) {
            writer.write(thisLine + '\n');
            numOfLinesRead++;
        }



        Dataset<Row> people = spark.read().csv("/home/vipin/mylocalfile.csv");

        /*Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().option("header", "true").option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
                .option("nullValue", "0").option("delimiter", ",")
                .csv("s3n://AKIAI6OYME7W2QAIIOAA:Cn1XhD72rEIRg7etAjhXFBQLRiverQgsnrtt+CRf@flightdata-em//2015/On_Time_On_Time_Performance_2015_1.csv");*/
        people.printSchema();
        people.show(10000, false);
        System.out.println("Total Time Taken " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
    }

}
```

in this way it's writing csv file into local file then spark is parsing it with a local file. So performance is decreasing. 
is there any solution to parse it without writing it localy?

Comment: Why cannot you just do call `spark.read.csv` with s3 location instead of local file? For example `spark.read.csv("s3n://flightdata-em/2015/On_Time_On_Time_Performance_2015_1.csv")`. For making it work you will need to add AWS key pair to you Spark configuration.

Comment: @Dmitry i have also used 
s3n://ACCESSKEY:SECRETKEY@flightdata-em//2015/On_Time_On_Time_Per‌​formance_2015_1.csv

but it's giving 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid hostname in URI s3://ACCESSKEY:SECRETKEY@flightdata-em/2015/On_Time_On_Time_Per‌​formance_2015_1.csv

Comment: AWS key pair should be provided when you create `SparkSession` as two additional configuration parameters, e.g.: `SparkSession.builder().appName("SparkCassandraApp").config("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", "yourAssesKeyId").config("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", "yourSecretAccessKey")`

Comment: @Dmitry thanks for helping me.